# Unable to load plugin nose-timer

Tags: python, nosetests

I set up a new machine to run nosetests with nose-timer plugin, and I have other machines in my environment that are running them with no problem.  I don't remember having to do anything special.  Does this have something to do with my path?  I have set my Path to

> C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packges;C:\Python27\Scripts;

but on the machines that work, I only have Python27 and \Scripts in the Path.

My versions of nosetest are both 1.3.1 but on working machines, nose-timer version is 0.3.0 and non-working is 0.4.3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
    assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
AssertionError: __main__
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\manager.py:395: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin nosetimer = nosetimer.plugin:TimerPlugin:
  RuntimeWarning)
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: --with-timer
```

Thanks in advance,
Boris

Answer (score 2):

I ended up downgrading to nose-timer 0.3.0 and my tests ran fine.

```
pip uninstall nose-timer
pip install nose-timer==0.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to this upstream pip issue with wheels: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1891

Installing `nose-timer` without wheel should resolve this issue:

```
pip install --no-use-wheel nose-timer
```